# PHP How to set a path to a Virtual Directory in IIS Windows 8.1

Tags: php, iis, windows-8.1, web-hosting

I have recently set up IIS on Win 8.1 machine to run a server for my  small perosnal requirement.

I have a lot of e-books saved in "%SystemDrive%\Users\admin\Google Drive\phpbooks" folder. I have recently found a way of dynamically indexing all my-ebooks in a catalog which I can then access from www. The program that does it is a php program running on iis.

Scenario 1:

When I copy and paste all my books from the above location to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\Books, this php program is able to locate the metadata file when I use this command:

"$config['calibre_directory'] = array ("Fiction" => "/inetpub/wwwroot/phpbooks/F7N5/", "Non-fiction" => "/inetpub/wwwroot/phpbooks/NF7N5/");"

in config_local.php file of the php app that I am using.

It is working fine, but the problem is that both the server and google drive folder are sitting on the same hard drive. Which means that I am duplicating the data.

This is what I am hoping to achieve:

Scenario 2:**

Create a virtual drive of the main google drive folder within IIS wwwroot folder. Change this command in config_local.php:

"$config['calibre_directory'] = array ("Fiction" => "/inetpub/wwwroot/phpbooks/F7N5/", "Non-fiction" => "/inetpub/wwwroot/phpbooks/NF7N5/");"

to a command which can correctly help this php program find its way to the google drive through the OS.

However, since I am not a php champion I don't know what syntax or command or script or code to use that will help point this program to the exact location of where the books are originally without the need to duplicate data on a server folder.

I hope I have been able to explain my issue clearly and comprehensively to you. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Kind regards,

Rishi Saran.

Comment: php has no knowledge of anything IIS is doing. you can create all the virtual drives/folders you want in IIS, but php will only see the actual underlying physical drive structure.

Comment: Thanks Marc. That clarifies it for me. So what will be the correct syntax or path to the above location in PHP if I have to change the path to the actual underlying physical drive structure. Any help would be great. Many thanks. Ps: I am an amateur in this field and learning everything along the way. Kind regards,Rishi Saran.